# Is it possible to import custom XML files with the Feed Import module?

Tags: 7, feeds

With the feed import module I see that you can import CSV files and RSS feeds. But what about custom XML files that follow our own defined format. Is it possible to tell the Feed Importer to import these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. You need the [Feeds Xpath Parser module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser)

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Feeds extensible parsers](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex) module which is more flexible than Xpath Parser which is more user friendly and supports more formats (including XPath XML & HTML).